# Restoring a lost svn history for a git project

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a project, that was migrated from SVN to git some time ago.

WELL. Not really migrated. The last SVN revision was copied into the initial git commit. So basically all SVN history was squashed into the first git commit.

Many commits have now been added to the git repository.

Is there a way to way to rebase the new git commits onto a properly converted git repo? So we have the full history again?

#### Edit:

I now have two git branches, one with all the old history (`old`), another with all the new history (`new`). There is no diff between the last commit of `old` and the first commit of `new`. How do I merge those histories into one?

Answer (score 1):

With a little work, sure. First, migrate correctly the svn repo into a git repo. Then add the git repo that you created from svn before (bad-remote, from now on) as a remote. When you fetch from it, you will be able to see the remote branches from bad-remote. Then rebase (or cherry-pick, whavever you think will be fine) the work that you did on bad-remote on top of the new svn branches on this repo.

```
git rebase --onto svn-full-history svn-short-history-first-revision-id svn-short-with-git-only-commits
```

That should apply all the git-only changes onto the full svn branch.

Comment: I now have two git branches, one with all the old history, another with all the new history. There is no diff between the last commit of `old` and the first commit of `new`.

How do I merge those histories into one?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understood. If I'm not mistaken what you mean is that you have fetched the full history of the svn branch (only working on a single svn branch, right?).. which I would assume I meant to call _new_ and then you can also see on this repo the git repository with the old sv branch plus a lot of work done on git and not on svn, which I would assume you would call _old_. You have compared the _first_ revision of old (which is the last revision of the project taken from svn) with the last revision of _new_ (which is the branch with the full story) and they are both the same

Comment: The next step would then be to ask git to put the git-only history of the old repo onto the new svn branch, right? I'll add the recipe on my original answer

Comment: This would work, if the new git history is just linear. However there are tons of merges and resolved conflicts git know wants to have resolved again

Comment: You could try to replicate the merges with --rebase-merges or --preserve-merges. `git help rebase` will provide you will all the gory details (including a full section on **rebasing merges**).

Comment: And if you don't mind getting your hands dirty.... like really dirty, you might consider replicating everything 'by hand' by using `git commit-tree`. You could write a script that goes through the git-only revisions of the old branch and replicate them on top of the new svn-branch with close to 0 work (other than writing the script) and replicating history without losing a single bit with the additional advantage of not having to solve any conflicts as you would be using the trees of the original revisions _as is_. Not for the faint of heart... but possible.

Comment: In the end, what I did was `git rebase --rebase-merges --onto svn_history initial_commit github_history`.

Then I still had to resolve all merge conflicts again, however, I did that semi-automatically by checking out the merge commit like this `git checkout <hash> -- .` Where hash is the merge commit.

So `git rebase --continue` would report something like `could not applly aabbccd...` then I would `git checkout aabbccd -- .` `git add .` `git rebase --continue` and so forth.